# Java endless Scanner loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Im trying to print the same strings as the user are pasting into the console.
My code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reader {
    public static void main(String[ ] args)  
    {   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        while ( scan.hasNextLine() ) {
            buf.append( scan.nextLine() );
            buf.append( "\n" );
        }

        String s = buf.toString();
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

The problem (i think) is that the loop is endless even if the user is only pasting 4 lines in the console it will not break the while loop.

What I want is the "System.out.print(s);" to print s. What should I do?Can I break the loop when the user is pressing Enter?

Comment: You need to define an endpoint. When do you *want* the loop to break?

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because the scanner will wait for input. Instead, check if the input is null (the user presses enter) and exit the loop:

```
String line;

while (!(line = scan.nextLine()).equals("")) {
    buf.append(line);
    buf.append("\n");
}
```

This will run until the user provides a blank line.

Comment: No, empty line will not return `null`

Comment: @Antoniossss It would return an empty string right?

Comment: Right now the user have to press Enter twice.
The problem is that the task that Im assigned to do only gives me the opportunity to press Enter once

Comment: @user3712130 In this code, you'd have to press enter once.

Comment: Well ye once after that you have submitted the text in the console. I want it to stop at the same Enter as when you submit the text

Answer (score 0):

You will have to break your loop after specified user input eg. `X Enter`. Your loop will never break by itsetf, as `Scanner` will try to read from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

You can end it after hitting enter twice.
The code would look like:

package Utilities;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reader {

```
public static void main(String[ ] args)  
{ 

Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
while ( scan.hasNextLine() ) {
    System.out.println("<<");
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    buf.append( line );
    buf.append( "\n" );
    System.out.println(line);
    if(line.equals(""))
        break;

}
String s = buf.toString();
System.out.print(s);
}
}
```

You can even use custom message like exit.

Comment: The problem is that the task that Im assigned to do only gives me the opportunity to press Enter once

Comment: It is as good as reading only one line. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hmm what do you mean?

Comment: Do you want the user to enter the text once and as soon as enter is hit, it should exit.